# Alter core and add wrapper twig template

Tags: theming

Our site has multiple block twig template in our theme (20+).  They are simple.   When the block is in the layout builder we need to add additional things (admin label, classes, etc), because nothing gets display when the block is empty.    I know we can modify each of our our templates, but we would rather move that logic into a block wrapper.

We are looking for all blocks to call a block-wrapper.html.twig (or something similar) before their suggested twig template.  Is there a way to alter Drupal's core logic?

Comment: try with hook_theme_suggestions_alter https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8.9.x

Comment: Have you tried adding wrapper in block.html.twig?

Comment: @berramou I know I can suggest a different block template to use, but I want to add an extra layer.  One to class a wrapper template then the block template

Comment: @NoSssweat we are using multiple block--X.html.twig templates so adding a wrapper to block.html.twig does not help